# vbs doesn't execute all code lines when there are events in excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a scripting newbie question. Tried to look for an answer, but was not able to find. Or wasn't able to formulated good enough for search engine to understand.
I'm trying to control excel from VBS. I wrote simple script in VBS. Script runs fine when there is no events in Excel. But when I for example press mouse button many times, VBS script does not execute all code lines in a FOR loop (only first of them is executed.
My code example:

```
dim FileName
dim firstCell
dim run_time
dim xlBook
dim i

FileName = "excelTaimeris.xlsx"


on error resume next
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
if err.number = 0 then

    Set xlBook = objExcel.Application.ActiveWorkBook

    if xlBook.Name = FileName then
        objExcel.DisplayAlerts = true
        objExcel.Visible =true

        Set firstCell = xlBook.ActiveSheet.range("A2")  'nustatom pirmaji laukeli automatiniam ejimui zemyn

        'doEvents
        for i=0 to 10
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            firstCell.offset(i-1,0).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            firstCell.offset(i, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        next

    else
        msgbox "wrong excel is open"
    end if
```

As I believe this is something to do with sharing CPU between OS and Excel. Should I implement some kind of way to check if VBS script executed the code line. If not, execute again?

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Remove `on error resume next` and read the error message.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for idea. I have removed this line. Then when I run script and then pressing mouse button for several times (quickly) in a workbook, I am getting error message "Unknown run time error" with a code 800AC472. It points to the 51st line char 4 (for..next loop line 2).